# Prevent Liquid from parsing of certain files in Jekyll

Tags: jekyll, liquid

I am using Jekyll + Liquid + Markdown to generate *static* html pages. Consequently, this is really a question specific to the Jekyll framework and Liquid template generator because there is syntax that conflicts with Liquid in some of my Markdown files.

Is there a quick and dirty work-around I can use for the time being in order to prevent Liquid from parsing certain files?

Comment: Which javascript framework ?

Comment: Hi David. No javascript only jekyll+liquid+markdown that generates static html files (want to keep things simple).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [Raw](https://shopify.github.io/liquid/tags/raw/):

> Raw temporarily disables tag processing. This is useful for generating content (eg, Mustache, Handlebars) which uses conflicting syntax.

```
{% raw %}
  In Handlebars, {{ this }} will be HTML-escaped, but
  {{{ that }}} will not.
{% endraw %}
```